# Find out easily which dependency versions are compatible

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package, version

So, if you have a bunch of dependencies in node and you don't regularly update them, but now you want to you may run into a bunch of these messages.

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.6.2 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @material-ui/core@3.9.2 wants react@^16.3.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer progress-arc-component@2.6.0 wants react@^15.5.4
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-autosuggest@9.4.3 wants react@>=0.14.7
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-datepicker@1.8.0 wants react@^16.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@15.6.2 wants react@^15.6.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-fa@4.2.0 wants react@>= 0.13.0 <16.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-hover-image@1.0.0 wants react@^16
...
```

Is there an easy way to find out which versions are compatible with a certain dependency? E,g find all versions of these packages that are compatible with `react@react@15.6.2`

Because, manually looking on NPM / GitHub to see what those versions are is a bit of a pain.

Comment: tried using `npm install` ?

Comment: `npm audit` should do it, that tracks the dependency tree without really fixing anything and only telling. And then may be `npm audit fix`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output posted in the question is already the list of incompatible peer dependencies. So you already found out about those incompatibilities. It also prints the required `semver` string so you could just use that in your `package.json`.

The whole point of peer dependencies is, that they are still managed by you and are not automatically resolved, but you can use `npm audit fix` to let npm try to fix it for you.

In this case however `react@>= 0.13.0 <16.0.0` is not compatible with some of the others, so I think it would not even be possible to find a version that meets all requirements.

Comment: Lets say I want to keep react@15.6.2 for whatever reason, then with this list I can't see which version of material-ui/core would work with it. I only know that the current one won't.

Comment: I added `npm audit fix` to the answer, to make it complete. Thanks.

Comment: @Matthijn OK, I understand what you mean, but I cannot think of a good solution for that. Just look at npm.org and go back major / minor version to find the latest compatible version. Normally you would just upgrading until its incompatible and then stop upgrading it further (If for some reason you have to stick with that old react version, which should also be avoided).